# What is the simplest way to write a UTF-8 encoded dictionary to .csv in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary, utf-8

I have a dictionary like this:

```
for i in wordlist:
    #some searching and parsing that produces one-line sentences, str1 and str2
    list1.append(str1)
    list2.append(str2)
    zipall = zip(list1, list2)
    mydict = {i: zipall}
```

where 'i' is a string. Everything is Cyrillic. When I print it, I get code points (\u0440\u0435 etc.).

I need to save the dictionary to a csv file row by row in every iteration so that i, str1 and str2 are in the same row and in separate columns, to be read by a user later on. When I try

```
with open('C:\...result.csv','wb') as f:  #I will need the 'a' mode?
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

and similar methods, I get this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Other stuff I've tried:

```
f = open('C:\...results.csv','wb')
w = csv.DictWriter(f,sorted(mydict.keys()))
w.writeheader() #throws error in this line
w.writerow({k:v.encode('utf8') for k,v in mydict.items()})
f.close()
```

(from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838605/python-dictwriter-writing-utf-8-encoded-csv-files)), and pickle, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508726/how-to-encode-python-dictionary). I've been trying to [iterate over the dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python?rq=1), but the value is a tuple and I can't encode it. There are answers which involve [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37376263/encode-the-elements-of-a-tuple) and what not (tried working with tuples), but I don't understand those methods (and they didn't work).

Is there a (simple) way?

**EDIT - ROUNDABOUT SOLUTION**

Since I don't really need the output to be csv, and the data will later be examined in Excel, I applied [the xlwt package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt). Got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet).

The package enables me to write into cells of an Excel spreadsheet with the specified encoding (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184454/has-anyone-been-able-to-write-out-utf-8-characters-using-pythons-xlwt)). I don't need dictionaries nor lists of tuples anymore. I just work with the result strings.

If there is a way to convert the xls to csv from Python, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: In this line `w.writerow({k:v.encode('utf8') for k,v in mydict.items()})`, `v` is a tuple, so it has no `encode` method. Try thinking in terms of the elements of the tuple, along these lines: `{k:tuple([vv.encode('utf8') for vv in v]) for k,v in mydict.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

The response is in the Python 2.7 documentation.

See: [13.1.5. Examples](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#examples)

You can define a `UnicodeWriter`, see below:

```
import cStringIO
import codecs
import csv


class UnicodeWriter(object):
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """
    # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods

    def __init__(self, ostream, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize the write with the output stream, the Excel dialect and the encoding.

        :param istream: Output stream to encode.
        :type istream: file like object.
        :param dialect: Excel dialect.
        :type dialect: Dialect
        :param encoding: Encoding to use.
        :type encoding: str
        """
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
        self.stream = ostream
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        """
        Write a row to the output stream (CSV file).

        :param row: List of UNICODE string to write.
        :type row: list of unicode
        """
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and re-encode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        """
        Write a list of rows. See: :meth:`writerow`.

        :param rows: List of rows.
        :type rows: list.
        """
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)
```

Here is a full implementation with Exception handling:

```
import csv
import sys


def to_unicode(obj):
    """ Convert an object to UNICODE string (robust way). """
    if obj is None:
        return u""
    elif isinstance(obj, unicode):
        return obj
    elif isinstance(obj, str):
        try:
            return unicode(obj, sys.getdefaultencoding())
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return unicode(repr(obj))
    else:
        return unicode(obj)


class CsvWriteException(ValueError):
    """
    Exception raised when a CSV file can't be written.
    """

    def __init__(self, csv_path, invalid_row, cause):
        """
        Initialize the exception.

        :param csv_path: Full path of the CSV file to read.
        :type csv_path: str
        :param invalid_row: Row to write but containing invalid values.
        :type invalid_row: list[unicode]
        :param cause: Exception cause of the problem.
        :type cause: Exception
        """
        super(CsvWriteException, self).__init__(csv_path, invalid_row, cause)

    def get_csv_path(self):
        """
        :return: Full path of the CSV file to read (unicode).
        """
        return self.args[0]

    def get_invalid_row(self):
        """
        :return: Row to write but containing invalid values (list of unicodes).
        """
        return self.args[1]

    def get_cause(self):
        """
        :return: Exception cause of the problem (Exception).
        """
        return self.args[2]

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.__unicode__())

    def __unicode__(self):
        msg_fmt = (u"Échec d'écriture du fichier {csv_path}, enregistrement invalide\u00a0: {invalid_row}. "
                   u"-- Cause: {cause}")
        csv_path = self.quote(self.get_csv_path())
        invalid_row = repr(self.get_invalid_row())
        cause = self.get_cause()
        err_msg = msg_fmt.format(csv_path=csv_path,
                                 invalid_row=invalid_row,
                                 cause=cause)
        return err_msg

    @staticmethod
    def quote(text):
        """
        Quote a text using the format '"{0}"', or the string "None" if the text is None.

        :param text: String to quote.
        :type text: str or unicode.
        :return: The quoted text or "None".
        """
        if text is None:
            return "None"
        else:
            if isinstance(text, str):
                escaped = unicode(text.replace('"', '\\"'), errors='replace')
            else:
                escaped = text.replace('"', '\\"')
            return u'"{0}"'.format(escaped)


def write_csv_file(csv_path, record_list, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8"):
    """
    Write the records to a CSV file on disk.

    See: :meth:`csv.list_dialects`: for a list of all registered dialects.

    :param csv_path: Full path of the CSV file to write.
    :type csv_path: str or unicode
    :param record_list: Records to write: list of dictionaries of the type (field_name, field_value).
    :type record_list: list[dict]
    :param dialect: The optional 'dialect' parameter can be given which is used to define a set of parameters
       specific to a particular CSV dialect. For example: "excel-tab" or "excel".
    :type dialect: Dialect or str or unicode
    :param encoding: Characters encoding to use to read the CSV file, default: "utf-8".
    :type encoding: str or unicode
    :raise CsvWriteException: Exception raised when a CSV file can't be written.
    """
    with open(csv_path, 'wb') as ostream:

        if len(record_list) == 0:
            # leave the file empty without header
            return

        writer = UnicodeWriter(ostream, dialect=dialect, encoding=encoding)

        curr_row = None

        try:
            # Write the header: list of fields.
            header = curr_row = record_list[0].keys()
            writer.writerow(curr_row)

            # Write records: list of values
            for record in record_list:
                curr_row = [record.get(key) for key in header]  # same order as header
                curr_row = [to_unicode(value) for value in curr_row]
                writer.writerow(curr_row)

        except (csv.Error, UnicodeEncodeError) as cause:
            raise CsvWriteException(csv_path, curr_row, cause)
```

Comment: How do I 'apply' the class to mydict and at what point do I do that? Do I simply write mydict.UnicodeWriter?

Answer (score 0):

You said you use cyrillic characters. By definition they are not in the ascii range, so you must encode them before writing them to a file. Assuming (per your title) that you want to use utf-8 encoding (others encoding could be possible such as cp1251...), just adapt your first try for explicit encoding:

```
with open('C:\...result.csv','wb') as f:  #I will need the 'a' mode?
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value.encode('utf8)'])
```

if only value is unicode, or

```
    ...
        writer.writerow([key.encode('utf8'), value.encode('utf8)'])
```

if both key and value are unicode (**you** may know, **I** cannot...)